# allow javascript to control some environmental things

Tags: javascript, java, java-11, graalvm

I want to use GraalVM to run user-written javascript code (I am writing a Java 11 project).

Can I give Java objects to the javascript file, in javascript I want to write something like

```
shrek.shedLayer();
```

and when my Java program executes this statement it is equivalent to as if it (the java program) had directly run

```
someLong.pieceOf().Code();
Maybe multipleLines = new Maybe();
someLong.add(multipleLines);
```

or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have your Java code evaluate JavaScript. Yes, you can pass Java objects to the JavaScript context. Yes, you can return JavaScript values into Java.

[Here's](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/blob/master/native-list-dir/ExtListDir.java) an example of the Java code that instantiates a JavaScript context, evaluates a string of JavaScript code that defines a function, stores this function in a variable, calls it passing Java objects as parameters and prints the return value of this function invocation.

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ExtListDir {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        final Context context = Context.create("js");
        String s = "name + ': ' + size";
        if (args.length == 1) {
            s = args[0];
        }
        final Value lambda = context.eval("js",
            "(function(name, size) { return " + s + "})");
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("."))) {
            paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach((Path p) -> {
                File f = p.toFile();
                Value v = lambda.execute(f.getName(), f.length());
                System.out.println(v);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use Java classes from the JS context, you can reference them with `Java.type()`, for example here's a [JS snippet which uses Java's BigInteger](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/blob/master/polyglot-javascript-java-r/server.js):

```
const BigInteger = Java.type('java.math.BigInteger');
var text = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(100)
          .add(BigInteger.valueOf(43)).toString();
```

Comment: But there's no example in there of JavaScript controlling the Java environment

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by "JavaScript controlling the Java environment" but if you want to create multiple Java contexts from JavaScript it doesn't work that way currently. I added a snippet to show how to access Java classes from JavaScript.